# How to create a list of DateTimes representing a recurring event regardless of daylight saving?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, dst

For example, a recurring event occurs every Saturday at 08:00 Central European Time (or 08:00 CEST during summers), regardless of whether there is DST or not. How do I come up with a list of `DateTime`s representing this event?

Comment: Do you mean 08:00 GMT+1 and 09:00 GMT+2 when DST takes place accordingly? Or always, 08:00 GMT+1 and 08:00 GMT+2? If second, it doesn't matter, you just need to schedule event on 08:00.

Comment: Base on the UTC time and the current timezone offset

Comment: But isn't current timezone offset taking DST into account?

Comment: A DateTime with a Kind property of DateTimeKind.Local, with a TimeOfDay property of 08:00, will have that same TimeOfDay property regardless of DST. Only when converting to UTC will the need to reckon with DST come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
List<DateTime> Schedule = new List<DateTime>();

DateTime Base = new DateTime(2013, 11, 9, 8, 0, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    Schedule.Add(Base.AddDays(i));
```

Comment: How do I set it to CET/CEST?

Comment: Dates in .NET do not have time zones beyond local/UTC. At most they can have offsets, which is sometimes (often?) enough.

Comment: Microsoft explains how here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  (Converting Times Between Time Zones)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get a list of `DateTimeOffset` values that accurately represent what you asked.  If you like, you can convert to `DateTime` with either `result.DateTime` or `result.UtcDateTime` depending on what you are looking for.  This will return the next N days from today, in the time zone provided, accounting for DST.

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset> GetNextDaysInZone(int count, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, TimeSpan localTimeOfDay, string timeZoneId)
{
    // get today in the time zone specified
    TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
    DateTime today = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz).Date;

    // figure out how many days we are away from the target day of week
    int adjustment = dayOfWeek - today.DayOfWeek + (dayOfWeek < today.DayOfWeek ? 7 : 0);

    // calculate and return the results
    return Enumerable.Range(0, count)
        .Select(x =>
        {
            DateTime dt = today.AddDays(x * 7 + adjustment).Add(localTimeOfDay);
            TimeSpan offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(dt);
            return new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
        });
}
```

Example usage:

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
TimeSpan localTimeOfDay = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);

// Note: Despite the name, this represents Central European Time, including both CET and CEST.
string tzid = "Central Europe Standard Time";

var results = GetNextDaysInZone(5, dayOfWeek, localTimeOfDay, tzid);

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} ({1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} UTC)", result, result.UtcDateTime);
}
```

Results:

```
2013-11-16 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-11-16 07:00:00 UTC)
2013-11-23 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-11-23 07:00:00 UTC)
2013-11-30 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-11-30 07:00:00 UTC)
2013-12-07 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-12-07 07:00:00 UTC)
2013-12-14 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-12-14 07:00:00 UTC)
```

And for good measure, if you'd like to ditch the built-in date/time api and go with something much more robust and reliable, I suggest you try [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  Here is how you might do the same thing as above using Noda Time.

```
public static IEnumerable<ZonedDateTime> GetNextDaysInZone(int count, IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek, LocalTime localTimeOfDay, string timeZoneId)
{
    // get today in the time zone specified
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZoneId];
    Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
    LocalDate today = now.InZone(tz).Date;

    // figure out how many days we are away from the target day of week
    int adjustment = dayOfWeek - today.IsoDayOfWeek + (dayOfWeek < today.IsoDayOfWeek ? 7 : 0);

    // calculate and return the results
    return Enumerable.Range(0, count)
        .Select(x => (today.PlusDays(x * 7 + adjustment) + localTimeOfDay).InZoneLeniently(tz));
}
```

Example Usage:

```
IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek = IsoDayOfWeek.Saturday;
LocalTime localTimeOfDay = new LocalTime(8, 0, 0);

// This is just one of the zones that follows CET/CEST
string tzid = "Europe/Berlin";

var results = GetNextDaysInZone(5, dayOfWeek, localTimeOfDay, tzid);

LocalDateTimePattern localPattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
OffsetPattern offsetPattern = OffsetPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("m");
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ({2} UTC)",
        localPattern.Format(result.LocalDateTime),
        offsetPattern.Format(result.Offset),
        localPattern.Format(result.WithZone(DateTimeZone.Utc).LocalDateTime));
}
```

Results:

```
2013-11-16 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-11-16 07:00:00 UTC)
2013-11-23 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-11-23 07:00:00 UTC)
2013-11-30 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-11-30 07:00:00 UTC)
2013-12-07 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-12-07 07:00:00 UTC)
2013-12-14 08:00:00 +01:00 (2013-12-14 07:00:00 UTC)
```

Both of these approaches take the path of assuming a lenient conversion for times that either don't exist or exist twice on the days of daylight saving time transitions.  If you'd like it to not be lenient, then you have some more work to do.  But I think that's beyond the scope of what you asked for.